# How does finding max by using >=all work?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to find the max count from the table and know how it is done using all. But I just don't understand how it works. Like when you say count(*)>=all(select count(*) rest of the query) then that just means that if the count is not greater than all of them then it can be equal to them? like how is that possible when there is more than one value in the subquery?

Here is my code

```
select 
    m.name,
    count(*) 
from 
    manufacturer m 
    inner join products p on m.code=p.manufacturer
group by m.name,m.code
having count(*)<=all(
    select count(*) 
    from manufacturer m
    inner join products p on m.code=p.manufacturer 
    group by m.code
);
```

Comment: if you have three rows with values 1,2,3 and you compare them with `>= ALL` against the same 3 values you will end up with the row with 3. Because this is the only one where the expression `left >= right` is true for **all** three of the values.

Comment: Thank you so much this is the explanation that I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/all-any-some-comparison-conditions-in-sql#all) :

> The ALL comparison condition is used to compare a value to a list or subquery. It must be preceded by =, !=, >, <, <=, >= and followed by a list or subquery.
>
> When the ALL condition is followed by a list, the optimizer expands the initial condition to all elements of the list and strings them together with AND operators

In your use case you would want :

```
... having count(*) >= all(select count(*) ...
```

Instead of :

```
... having count(*) <= all(select count(*) ...
```

This will return the item whose count is equal to the maximum possible value (or more than one item if there are top ties).

However there are simpler options to obtain the result you want. Just order the results of your query and use ROWNUM to select the top row, like :

```
select * from (
    select m.name,count(*) cnt
    from 
        manufacturer m 
        inner join products p 
            on m.code=p.manufacturer 
    group by m.name,m.code
    order by 2 desc
) where rownum = 1
```

Comment: Yeah I know this method but I just want to know how all would work in this case

Comment: @sania247... ALL is not relevant for your use case... this new query should perform better than the one you provided